# Does present participle without comma always modifies preceding noun or noun phrase?

Tags: commas, present-participles

When reading the newspaper, I came across this sentence:

> Then, Google’s Threat Analysis Group (TAG) put out a detailed blog post
> last week **explaining** how they believed Hermit was being used to target
> devices.

I am confused as to whether or not the word *explaining* is modifying the noun phrase *a detailed blog* because according to some grammar book I read:

> If the VERB-*ing* modifier (present participle) appears after a clause and **without a comma**, then it modifies the preceding noun or noun phrase.

But in this case, the syntactic constituent immediately preceding
*explaining* is *last week*, which is not a noun or noun phrase.

Can a present participial clause modify a more distant noun or noun phrase
even without a mandatory written comma? That is what is actually confusing
me, because some grammar book also says that when a participial phrase concludes a main clause and modifies a word
farther back in the sentence that the last thing, **you will *need* a comma**.

But there is no comma in my newspaper’s sentence; **why not?** How can this still be
grammatical in the English language without a written comma? Has the newspaper made a mistake in English grammar and created something that it not grammatical?

Comment: This: Then, Google's Threat Analysis Group (TAG) put out a detailed blog post last week explaining how they believed Hermit was being used to target devices.'' **means the same thing as: Then, Google's Threat Analysis Group (TAG) put out a detailed blog post last week **and explained** how they believed Hermit was being used to target devices.'' It is very common in English to use a verb phrase instead of second verb in the third person.

Comment: There is difference in the meaning between the TAG posted and then explained,  and the blog post which they posted was explaining behalf of their. I am bit confuse actually that the explaining is modifying to which TAG or a detailed blog post.

Comment: The blog post was explaining or explained how they believed, etc.

Comment: You keep saying that you are "confuse", but that isn't English. If you **confuse** someone, then that person becomes **confuse*d***. It's like when you scare someone, they become scared.

Comment: I don't know confuse is appropriate word in this case or not .l am not native speaker but I have some doubts regarding use of english grammar rules and I am trying to clear it out.

Comment: Yes: it modifies "detailed blog" (or just "blog"). "Last week" is not part of the NP, but a temporal adjunct in clause structure. It's the semantic equivalent of the relative construction: _a detailed blog post last week [which explained how they believed Hermit was being used to target devices_].

Comment: So, temporal adjunct can be used between present participle and noun which it is modifying.

Comment: Yes, it can. Postposing of non-finite clauses in NP structure is fairly common, as is postposing of relative clauses, as in _I met a **man** the other day **who says he knows you**_.

Comment: *Last week* is most definitely a noun phrase. And commas are just figments of the transcriber’s imagination; they are not part of English grammar, which comprises syntax and morphology.  Therefore the grammar must be clear in speech and writing is immaterial.

Comment: No, 'last week' is not  a noun phrase here, it is modifying the verb 'put out' so it is playing a role of adverb of time here. It is answering the question 'When they put out?' Ans- last week (adverb of time).

Comment: @Anshk No: "week" is a noun modified by "last", so "last week" is a noun phrase, here functioning as an adjunct (adverbial). It's important to distinguish word class (part of speech) and function.

Comment: Can I put 'last week' from the starting, so that I can write 'explaining ' after the noun 'blog post' to be less ambiguous.

Comment: ,,"I have read your paper, which is very well-written, carefully."   Can I write this sentence in different way as "l have read your paper carefully, which is well-written. Will it be grammatically correct??